# Need to know about the best Managed File Transfer tools available in market considering all the major constraints

Tags: file-transfer, websphere-mq-fte

Need to know about the best Managed File Transfer tools available (Open source or licensed) in market considering all the major constraints. Most importantly it should be used for enterprise integration with high availability. I have worked with some MFT tools but each has its own advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: see http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/24987/18099

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you've done the Google research on MFT solutions, so I will assume you're looking for  personal opinions to validate the direction you're already headed.

I've evaluated Linoma, IpSwitch, Townsend, GlobalScape, Liaison, and Axway. I've got a comparison table somewhere that I put together for our analysis that outlined what I needed in a solution and found that Linoma best fit the bill.

I've now used Linoma's GoAnywhere MFT solution for a few years and am still very pleased with it.  The company keeps up with the changing technologies, it has very powerful scripting capabilities yet keeps it simple to manage and administer.  Key management, scheduling, alerts, logging, role management, HA integration, data manipulation, multi-platform, mobile app, and more are some of the many functions.  But one of the best things about Linoma is their dedicated support team.  They are the best I've worked with.

Here's a link to their information: http://www.goanywheremft.com/products/director

Good luck in your search.

Comment: Thanks Herrmann and Daniel

Comment: Linoma GoAnywhere MFT does support application clustering for high(er) availability.